# ADB not showing logs on Studio and ADB applications on phone

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile, android-logcat

I am having a note edge Verizon N915V with Marshmallow updated (V6.0.1). The device is also rooted. After the update I am not able to see the ADB logs when I connect the device on Android Studio (V2.1.2). I have also installed the ADB Logcat applications from playstore but those also show no logs on the application. 
Things I have tried.

1. I have enabled the USB debugging.
2. Tried restarting and reconnecting the device and tried on other machines.
3. Note: There is no USB permission revoke option present in my developer option. I tried removing /system/etc/permissions android.hardware.usb.host.xml still no use.
4. adb commands works adb devices list my device as device only (not unauthorized, so its valid). adb push , adb pull also works
5. adb logcat is not working, when I enter that its on waiting mode.

In  My studio when I connect the device its listed on the android monitor window and all the process are listed on the dropdown, but what ever process I choose no adb logs comes. verbose and no filter options all methods tried no hope.

Comment: Fist verify if the integration of ADB is enabled into android studio. Go to Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration.

Comment: check your task manager, i think there are multiple adb running in background if not than Go to Tools > Android > Enable ADB after that invalidate and restart your android studio

Comment: Update on the issue. The abd logcat is not working on my mobile. The other devices connected to my PC shows adb logs.  But my mobile is not showing any logs.  I have tried command line adb logcat it's freezes.  My mobile is Samsung note edge N915v.  Running marshmallow.